# do custom things inside handleSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm new using react-hook-form and I need to validate some things outside the `react-hook-form` validation.

```
const Form = () => {
  const formOptions = { resolver: yupResolver(validationFormSchema) };
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm(formOptions);

  const handleAddImg = (e) => {
    const fileListArrayImg = Array.from(e.target.files);
    validateImgs(fileListArrayImg); // Here I validate the images added
  };

  const submitFunction = async (formData) => {
// Now I'm validating the images here.
// This validations don't execute unless the 'name' input validations are ok.
// So never renders at the same time the 'name' input errors and the 'image' errors.
// That's what I need.
  };

  return (
    <form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitFunction)}>
      <input type="text" {...register("name")} />
      <span>{errors.name?.message}</span>

      <input
        type="file"
        name="image"
        multiple
        accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
        onChange={handleAddImg}
      />
      <CustomError>Custom errors renders here</CustomError>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};
```

When I submit the form, the validation happens inside `handleSubmit` and if there's an error, `submitFunction` is not executed.

I'm validating some things with `react-hook-form`, and need to validate files (and other things happening in custom components) at the same time as the `react-hook-form` validations. I mean, I need to do custom validations inside `handleSubmit` before `submitFunction` is executed, so the `react-hook-form` errors and my custom validations errors can render at the same time.

How can I do that?

EDIT

I could do it this way

```
  const customFunction = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    customValidations();
    return handleSubmit(submitProduct)(e);
  };

<form encType="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={customFunction}>
```

Comment: could you try `onSubmit={()=>handleSubmit(submitFunction)}`

Comment: I need to execute a **customFunction** inside **handleSubmit** before **submitFunction** is executed.

Comment: is it possible to provide the code?

Comment: Why can't you do it on submit? You can e.preventDefault() to stop the submission if it fails validation

Comment: As shown, unless `handleSubmit` returns a function, things are already funky--the handler should be a function, not the results of calling a function (unless, again, `handleSubmit` returns a function). What's the specific issue, though? `handleSubmit` can be wrapped however you want if it's coming from `useForm`, and we know what `handleSubmit` receives because of its docs.

Comment: I cleaned and provided the code, the form and `react-hook-form` validations are working. I need to render at the same time `react-hook-form errors` and my `custom errors` when the form is submitted.